# Code breaks after cleaning-up

Tags: javascript, json, coding-style, code-cleanup

I am new to JavaScript and I'm learning how to make my code more readable and get away from inline functions. I have a code that loops through a JSON array of comments and then appends the comments to the DOM. When it's "messy" it works, then all of a sudden I try to clean it up and for some reason it stops working.

Can anyone pinpoint why? This is the "messy" one:

```
var myCommentArray = [
    {
        _id: "888888888888888888",
        index: 1,
        name: "Perez",
        message: "First Comment .......",
        subject: "enim officias",
        replies: [ // notice this comment has replies (just 1 but it is still an array)
            {
                _id: "77777777777777777777",
                index: 0,
                name: "Reply to First Comment Ines for Perez",
                message: "...",
                subject: "reply subject consequat"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        _id: "999999999999",
            index: 0,
            name: "Shelton",
            message: "2nd Comment....a",
            subject: "enim irure",
            replies: null // notice this comment has no replies and as such is null. this is better than an empty array
    },
    {
        _id: "666666666666666666",
        index: 2,
        name: "Perez",
        message: "3rd Comment.......",
        subject: "enim officias",
        replies: [
            {
                _id: "55555555555555555555",
                index: 0,
                name: "1st Reply to 3rd Comment",
                message: "...",
                subject: "reply subject consequat"
            },
            {
                _id: "44444444444444444444",
                index: 1,
                name: "2nd Reply to 3rd Comment",
                message: "...",
                subject: "reply subject consequat"
            }
        ]
    }
];

var stringedArray = JSON.stringify(myCommentArray);
var parsedCommentArray = JSON.parse(stringedArray);

$.each(parsedCommentArray, function (i, val) {
    var currentComment = parsedCommentArray[i];
    var commentsFormat = '<br> <div class="comment-avatar media-left"> <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="avatar">' +
        '</div><div class="comment-content media-body clearfix"> <div class="comment-avatar media-left"></div><h3 class="media-heading">' +
        currentComment.subject + '</h3> <div class="comment-meta">By ' + currentComment.name + '</div> <div class="comment-body"> <p>'
    + currentComment.message + '</p><a href="#" class="btn btn-gray more  reply">' +
        '<i class="fa fa-reply"> </i> Reply </a> </div> </div>';
    $('.comments').append(commentsFormat);
});
```

And this is the "clean" one:

```
 sabio.page.startUp = function () {
     var myCommentArray = sabio.page.getMyArray();

     var obj = JSON.parse(myCommentArray);

     $.each(obj, sabio.page.proccessComments);

     $("#submissionButton").on('click', sabio.page.handlers.onSubmit);

 }


 sabio.page.proccessComments = function (i, currentComment) {

    var commentsFormat = '<br> <div class="comment-avatar media-left"> <img src="http://placehold.it/50x50" alt="avatar">' +
         '</div><div class="comment-content media-body clearfix"> <div class="comment-avatar media-left"></div><h3 class="media-heading">' + currentComment.subject + '</h3> <div class="comment-meta">By ' + currentComment.name + '</div> <div class="comment-body"> <p>' + currentComment.message + '</p><a href="#" class="btn btn-gray more  reply">' +
         '<i class="fa fa-reply"> </i> Reply </a> </div> </div>';

      $('.comments').append(commentsFormat);
  }


  sabio.page.handlers.onSubmit = function () {
      $(".comments").toggle();
      $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: $(".comments").offset().top
      }, 2000);

  }

  sabio.page.getMyArray = function () {
      var myArray = [{
          _id: "888888888888888888",
          index: 1,
          name: "Perez",
          message: "First Comment .......",
          subject: "enim officias",
          replies: [ // notice this comment has replies (just 1 but it is still an array)
          {
              _id: "77777777777777777777",
              index: 0,
              name: "Reply to First Comment Ines for Perez",
              message: "...",
              subject: "reply subject consequat"
          }]
      }, {
          _id: "999999999999",
          index: 0,
          name: "Shelton",
          message: "2nd Comment....a",
          subject: "enim irure",
          replies: null // notice this comment has no replies and as such is null. this is better than an empty array
      }, {
          _id: "666666666666666666",
          index: 2,
          name: "Perez",
          message: "3rd Comment.......",
          subject: "enim officias",
          replies: [{
              _id: "55555555555555555555",
              index: 0,
              name: "1st Reply to 3rd Comment",
              message: "...",
              subject: "reply subject consequat"
          }, {
              _id: "44444444444444444444",
              index: 1,
              name: "2nd Reply to 3rd Comment",
              message: "...",
              subject: "reply subject consequat"
          }]
      }];

      return myArray;

  }
```

Comment: Does the developer console show any errors?

Comment: Yes, it's saying Uncaught TypeError: sabio.page.getMyArray is not a function

Comment: Is the sabio.page object instantiated before declaring sabio.page.getMyArray?

Comment: that was the issue thanks codemax, I found that out by trial and error I didn't realize the order mattered so much, this is my first big (to me) project like this!

Answer (score 0):

Your `.getMyArray()` method already returns an object which you can iterate. There is no need for parsing it, specially with `var obj = JSON.parse(myCommentArray);` since it's not a valid JSON string. You can just have

```
var myCommentArray = sabio.page.getMyArray();
$.each(myCommentArray, sabio.page.proccessComments);
```

Comment: Thanks Griffith, the console says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined, and I'm not sure what that means really, I'm not sure what part is undefined if you have any other ideas please share

Comment: Where are you invoking `call`?

Comment: I honestly don't know, does that mean that I am calling an undefined function? What do you mean invoking call?...I just want to be good at this like you..

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of the developer console?

Comment: http://content.screencast.com/users/lyrana/folders/Default/media/7f81bdec-0489-46b2-ab31-25d95d0cf96d/console.jpg

Comment: The method `sabio.page.proccessComments()` seems to be undefined